# VBA vlookup, cut & paste

Tags: vba, excel

I'm starting to think that I'm a mile off with this code.  I want to find the value in "r15" and find a match in the lookup table.  Then, in that row and 2 columns to the right, I want to paste the value from e15.  Here's what I have:

```
Sub CopyX()
    MsgBox "FlightPlan for Profits PRO never actually DELETES an employee, It just marks an employee as inactive.  If the Employee were actually deleted from the database, archival records would not include a deleted employee (of course) and would therefore become inaccurate", vbInformation, "FlightPlan for Profits PRO"
    ActiveSheet.Range("e15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    vlookupVBA = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Range("r15"), Range("c24:c274"), 1, False)
        Range.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the question? what is the problem you've faced?

Comment: oh.  Sorry.  It doesn't work.  It doesn't paste anything.  And the range offset syntax must be wrong because I get an error there

Comment: Yes, but you are using VLOOKUP to return the same value that it is looking up. Show some sample data and provide some narrative about what your are trying to do. In any event, the VLOOKUP is cancelling hte .Copy so there is no .Paste.

Answer (score 1):

You were using the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) incorrectly. In fact, a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) would return the row number which was what you seemed to be looking for.

```
Sub CopyX()

    MsgBox "FlightPlan for Profits PRO never actually DELETES an employee." & Chr(10) & _
           "It just marks an employee as inactive. " & _
           "If the Employee were actually deleted from the database, archival records " & _
           "would not include a deleted employee (of course) and would therefore become inaccurate", _
           vbInformation, "FlightPlan for Profits PRO"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'first check if anything is there
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Range("c24:c274"), .Range("r15").Value)) Then
            'there is a row number to find; get it and set the value
            .Cells(Application.Match(.Range("r15").Value, .Range("c24:c274"), 0) + 23, "E") = _
                .Range("e15").Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

With MATCH returning the *position within* C24:C274, 23 is added and that provides the correct *row_number* parameter for the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) to receive the value from E15.

I've added a line feed and broken your msgbox text into a couple of lines to keep it visible without right-scrolling.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out later and keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Find will work for this as well.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim msg As String
    Dim lstRw As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C24:C" & lstRw)

    Set c = rng.Find(what:=Range("R15").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

    msg = "FlightPlan for Profits PRO never actually DELETES an employee, " & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & "It just marks an employee as inactive. " & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & "If the Employee were actually deleted from the database, " & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & "archival records would not include a deleted employee (of course) " & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & " and would therefore become inaccurate"
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "FlightPlan for Profits PRO"

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 2).Value = Range("E15").Value
    Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If


End Sub
```